# "Error: not found: value myparallel" on import statement

Tags: scala, jetbrains-ide

I am using JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA with the Scala plugin, I have a package.scala file inside `main/scala/myparallel` directory with the following code:

```
package myparallel

import java.util.concurrent._
import scala.util.DynamicVariable

object primitives {

  def time[R](block: => R): R = {
    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    val result = block    // call-by-name
    val t1 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time: " + (t1 - t0)/1000000 + "ms")
    result
  }

  val forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool

  abstract class TaskScheduler {
    def schedule[T](body: => T): ForkJoinTask[T]
    def parallel[A, B](taskA: => A, taskB: => B): (A, B) = {
      val right = task {
        taskB
      }
      val left = taskA
      (left, right.join())
    }
  }

  class DefaultTaskScheduler extends TaskScheduler {
    def schedule[T](body: => T): ForkJoinTask[T] = {
      val t = new RecursiveTask[T] {
        def compute = body
      }
      forkJoinPool.execute(t)
      t
    }
  }

  val scheduler =
    new DynamicVariable[TaskScheduler](new DefaultTaskScheduler)

  def task[T](body: => T): ForkJoinTask[T] = {
    scheduler.value.schedule(body)
  }

  def parallel[A, B](taskA: => A, taskB: => B): (A, B) = {
    scheduler.value.parallel(taskA, taskB)
  }

  def parallel[A, B, C, D](taskA: => A, taskB: => B, taskC: => C, taskD: => D): (A, B, C, D) = {
    val ta = task { taskA }
    val tb = task { taskB }
    val tc = task { taskC }
    val td = taskD
    (ta.join(), tb.join(), tc.join(), td)
  }

}
```

I use this code in various .sc worksheet files by importing it with `import myparallel.primitives._` such as this example:

```
import myparallel.primitives._
import scala.util.Random

val threshold = 10000

def mapArrPar[A,B](inp: Array[A], left: Int, right: Int,
                   f : A => B, out: Array[B]): Unit = {
  if (right - left < threshold)
    mapArr(inp, left, right, f, out)
  else {
    val mid = left + (right - left)/2
    parallel(mapArrPar(inp, left, mid, f, out),
      mapArrPar(inp, mid, right, f, out))
  }
}

val vectIn = Array.fill(100000)(1).map(_ * scala.util.Random.nextInt)
val vectOut = new Array[Double](100000)

time(mapArrPar(vectIn, 0, vectIn.length, (x:Int) => Math.pow(x, 19), vectOut))
```

The linter does not give me any errors, but if I try to execute the worksheet I obtain a series of errors, the first of them says `Error:not found: value myparallel
import myparallel.primitives._`. Moreover there are other errors for each use of functions defined in the previously mentioned package, such as `Error:(51, 6) not found: value parallel
 parallel(mapArrPar(inp, left, mid, f, out),`

What is wrong with the package or the import statement?

Comment: You probably didn´t compile it because it works fine with me, also you have a typo there, mapArr* -> mapArrPar

Comment: You are right, I though executing the worksheet would automatically compile the package, but that's not the case. The typo instead comes from copy-pasting snippets here (I did not include all the code), on my full code it is correct.
Thanks!